# Reduce memory size of video having videoQuality:UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeIFrame960x540

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, iphone-5

I am recording and uploading video to server from my iPhone application. The video needs to have a aspect ratio of 16:9 so I set

```
[videoRecorderController setVideoQuality:UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeIFrame960x540]
```

but the video of few seconds takes several MBs space.

Is there any way out to reduce the memory size of the video and maintaining the 16:9 aspect ratio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This helped me:

```
- (void)convertVideoToLowQuailtyWithInputURL:(NSURL*)inputURL
                               outputURL:(NSURL*)outputURL
                                 handler:(void (^)(AVAssetExportSession*))handler

{

AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:inputURL options:nil];
AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:asset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality];
exportSession.outputURL = outputURL;
exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;

[exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^(void)
 {
     handler(exportSession);
 }];
}
```